# How do I use animated picture in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, animation, image

It's possible to upload animation image on Facebook?

I found this **[picture](http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc3/27977_126383857373567_123901794288440_322191_439389_s.jpg)** is animation and I'm a bit confused. Why `jpg` can be animated?

**[Live](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=126383857373567)** example on Facebook. I saved this picture and re-upload to my wall and it's being static.

Anybody can explain it. Let me know.

Comment: http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc3/27977_126383857373567_123901794288440_322191_439389_s.gif also exists. I think it's a gif. It's a very cute kitten though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be an animated GIF with the headers munged enough to pass as a JPEG.  It's not perfect, most of my system's file viewers choke on it - but it's apparently enough for Facebook.  Your browser is written to be more fault-tolerant and automatically figures out that it's really a GIF, and displays the animation.

This is, of course, an exploit.  If you reposted the image to Facebook or attempted to repeat the trick on another movie, you could be banned.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook disables animations by making a static copy of animated GIFs. This is very much on purpose and is probably a response to the way that animations got out of hand on MySpace back in the day.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link...

http://apps.facebook.com/animated-picture/?upload

Make request to "CrazyDaVinci" to convert gif to mp3

And share through feed dialog to Facebook.